# 2D array using a function to scan for pairs

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

I created this function that scans a 2D array for vertical pairs, where row = 20 and column = 30. To clarify random characters from A to Z are stored in each of the array's elements.

```
char function3 (char randchar_array[ROW] [COLUMN]) 

{
int r = 0 ;
int c = 0 ;
int vertpairs = 0;

 for (r = 0; r < ROW ; r++)
 {
     for (c = 0; c < COLUMN -1; c++)
     {
       {
       if(randchar_array[r][c] == randchar_array[r+1][c])
         vertpairs++;
       }
     }
  }

  return (vertpairs);
}
```

My question is: Is the -1 necessary for the 2nd for statement " for (c = 0; c < COLUMN -1; c++)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, from the code (which compares vertically) it seems the `- 1` should be on the outer loop instead.

Now it will compare at `randchar_array[ROW - 1 + 1][c]` which is out of bounds, and gives undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, could you take a look at the rest of the code and tell me what you think needs to be fixed/changed. I'm new to programming and am having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.